# How to fix Wordpress Fatal error showing on mobile devices

Tags: wordpress

Help needed, I keep seeing this message whenever I login from mobile devices.

Fatal error:

> Class 'Inwave_Helper' not found
>   in /home1/centasou/centabiz.site/wp-content/plugins/inwave-common/shortcodes/map.php on
>   line 13

Comment: Hey, this question doesn't contain enough information to provide a good answer. As it currently is asked the correct answer is 'To remove the error add the `Inwave_Helper` class to the app'. That is probably not the answer that you need though, right?

Comment: I think this question is not suitable for stackoverflow and we can't really help you with this amount of information. Maybe you should ask the [theme developers](https://inwave.ticksy.com/) instead

Comment: @ Tom still wondering why you said my question is not suitable when i clearly spelled out the message "Fatal error " displayed when everi try to login on mobile devices. I belive as a professional you must have seen such error before.